# Unable to see option to add a user in Airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I have installed MWAA 2.0 and I am the root user of this setup and I am not finding the option to add a user. I want to add a IAM user and so that he can trigger EMR from Airflow.

How to add a existing IAM user to AIrflow  (presuming that user has access to create EMR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right here. But unfortunately This is a bug from the Airflow. Please check the jira here.

https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/18290

We have the similar issue and below is hack/workaround for this.

- We ask the user to try a login and fail. Once that happens we check
- the Security >> List Users  Then we change the role for that User and
- He/she is able to access after that.

Please let me know if that helped.